# bootstrap-wysiwyg-master post to php

Tags: php, bootstrap-wysiwyg

I have a problem with the bootstrap-wysiwyg-master edit

I want to post it to a php file to update a mysql table
and I don't know how to do.

My code :

```
  <div class="container">

  <form name="myform" id="myform">

  <div class="hero-unit">

    <div id="alerts"></div>
    <div class="btn-toolbar" data-role="editor-toolbar" data-target="#editor">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Font"><i class="icon-font"></i><b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          </ul>
        </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Font Size"><i class="icon-text-height"></i>&nbsp;<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a data-edit="fontSize 5"><font size="5">Huge</font></a></li>
          <li><a data-edit="fontSize 3"><font size="3">Normal</font></a></li>
          <li><a data-edit="fontSize 1"><font size="1">Small</font></a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn" data-edit="bold" title="Bold (Ctrl/Cmd+B)"><i class="icon-bold"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" data-edit="italic" title="Italic (Ctrl/Cmd+I)"><i class="icon-italic"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" data-edit="strikethrough" title="Strikethrough"><i class="icon-strikethrough"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" data-edit="underline" title="Underline (Ctrl/Cmd+U)"><i class="icon-underline"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn" data-edit="insertunorderedlist" title="Bullet list"><i class="icon-list-ul"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" data-edit="insertorderedlist" title="Number list"><i class="icon-list-ol"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" data-edit="outdent" title="Reduce indent (Shift+Tab)"><i class="icon-indent-left"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" data-edit="indent" title="Indent (Tab)"><i class="icon-indent-right"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn" data-edit="justifyleft" title="Align Left (Ctrl/Cmd+L)"><i class="icon-align-left"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" data-edit="justifycenter" title="Center (Ctrl/Cmd+E)"><i class="icon-align-center"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" data-edit="justifyright" title="Align Right (Ctrl/Cmd+R)"><i class="icon-align-right"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" data-edit="justifyfull" title="Justify (Ctrl/Cmd+J)"><i class="icon-align-justify"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Hyperlink"><i class="icon-link"></i></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu input-append">
                <input class="span2" placeholder="URL" type="text" data-edit="createLink"/>
                <button class="btn" type="button">Add</button>
        </div>
        <a class="btn" data-edit="unlink" title="Remove Hyperlink"><i class="icon-cut"></i></a>

      </div>

      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn" title="Insert picture (or just drag & drop)" id="pictureBtn"><i class="icon-picture"></i></a>
        <input type="file" data-role="magic-overlay" data-target="#pictureBtn" data-edit="insertImage" />
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn" data-edit="undo" title="Undo (Ctrl/Cmd+Z)"><i class="icon-undo"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" data-edit="redo" title="Redo (Ctrl/Cmd+Y)"><i class="icon-repeat"></i></a>
      </div>
      <input type="text" data-edit="inserttext" id="voiceBtn" x-webkit-speech="">
    </div>

    <div id="editor">
      Go ahead&hellip;
    </div>


       <input type="hidden" id="html" />


      <label>
        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
      </label>
  </div><!-- / hero-unit-->

      </form>


    </div><!-- / container-->

    <script>
    $('#editor').wysiwyg();
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn btn-primary').click(function() {

    var html = $('#editor').val();
    // Put this in the hidden field
    $("#html").val(html);
    $.ajax({
            url: 'update.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                content: content
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I don't know how to send the content of the div "editor" to the php page
Thank's fot help

Yves

Answer (score 4):

Yves,
In order to get the contents of the richtext editor to submit to a PHP page, create a hidden text input on the same page as the richtext editor, in the same form. Then add an onSubmit function to your form that copies the contents of the div to the hidden text input.  It would look something like:

```
<form name="my_form" method="post" onSubmit="document.my_form.editor_contents.value = $('#editor').html()">
<textarea name="editor_contents" style="display:none;"></textarea> 
<!-- put all your editor code here -->
<input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="submit"></form>
<!-- This assumes that your richtext editor div has an ID of 'editor'. -->
```